# Suppress Specific Doxygen Warnings

Tags: c, doxygen

It seems others have asked this question before. Just wanted to check and see if an answer had been found.

I have several occurrences of the following situation: as I am documenting various functions, sometimes I run into the situation where I wish to document some function parameters but not others.  For example,

```
/** 
 * This is the brief description for the function.
 * And here is the detailed description.
 * @param foo This parameter is not self-explanatory and needs a blurb
 */
void some_function(void *foo, int self_explanatory) {
    // function does stuff
}
```

Adding the `self_explanatory` parameter to the Doxygen documentation just adds clutter, so I'd rather leave it out. However, Doxygen warns that the parameter is undocumented. I'm using Eclox, and it's annoying to have a bunch of warnings highlighted that I don't care about.

Right now, my doxyfile has the following options set:

```
EXTRACT_ALL          = YES
WARNINGS             = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED = NO
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR    = YES
WARN_NO_PARAM_DOC    = NO
```

The warnings are still generated.

One option is to add `@cond` and `@endcond` surrounding the offending code, but then none of the documentation is generated for my function(s). I want the documentation, just not the warnings.

What I'm looking for is something like...

```
/** @nowarn
 * This is the brief description for the function.
 * And here is the detailed description.
 * @param foo This parameter is not self-explanatory and needs a blurb
 * @endnowarn
 */
void some_function(void *foo, int self_explanatory) {
    // function does stuff
}
```

... so that warnings are not generated in the enclosed code block.

Other SO questions I've found:
[Suppressing Doxygen warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506415/suppressing-doxygen-warnings)
[Suppress doxygen warning for undocumented member function, but leave synopsis in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993250/suppress-doxygen-warning-for-undocumented-member-function-but-leave-synopsis-in)
[Is it possible to choose which Doxygen warning to show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334010/is-it-possible-to-choose-which-doxygen-warning-to-show)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I usually write

```
@param self_explonatory
```

(just declare param without any description). This is usually sensible as param then shows in param table.

(still, I'd really like to have some option to disable warnings temporarily for other cases…)

Answer (score -2):

Just document the self_explanatory parameter, or keep in mind that warnings are just that: warnings. All Doxygen is telling you is that there is something you might have overlooked.

You can take the warning or just ignore it. If you really want to suppress that warning, you might want to look in the first thread you linked. Specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25137529/3121160.

Comment: Poor response. You did not provide any information that was not already supplied in the original question. I would like to suppress the warnings because I am using eclox, and large numbers of warnings is not acceptable. And I do not wish to document self-explanatory parameters in order to avoid generating noise in the source files.